# Can typescript infer type of other properties during object assignment

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inference

I'm working on a large Sanity.io CMS project that involves writing a lot of JS to define content types such as below:

```
const person = {
  type: 'document',
  name: 'person',
  fieldsets: [
    { name: 'personalDetails', title: 'Personal Details' },
  ],
  fields: [
    { name: 'firstName', type: 'string', fieldset: 'personalDetails' },
    { name: 'surname', type: 'string', fieldset: 'personalDetails' },
  ],
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a Document interface / type that can infer the names of the `fieldsets` provided and then use them to restrict the type of the `fieldset` property of objects in the `fields` array to a union of string literals. It's a small thing but it'd speed up development by enabling me to take advantage of autocomplete while churning out these content types.

My initial attempt looked like this:

```
interface Document {
  type: 'document';
  name: string;
  fieldsets: ReadonlyArray<{ name: string; title: string; }>;
  fields: Array<{
    name: string;
    type: string;
    fieldset: this['fieldset'][number]['name']; // Error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface
  }>
}
```

I understand the error and have tried various workarounds but can't achieve what I'm after without resorting to using a generic type and supplying an array of fieldset names:

```
interface Document<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> {
   /*  ...rest of definition  */
   fieldset: ReadonlyArray<{ name: T[number] }>
   fields: Array<{
     name: string;
     type: string;
     fieldset: T[number];
   }>
}

const person: Document<['personalDetails']> = {
  /* works, but not exactly what I'm after */
}
```

So is it possible for TypeScript to infer that type on the fly during assignment, or am I looking for something that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you need to use a generic to type this properly.  Typescript cannot infer a generic from a constant.  It *can* infer a generic from function call.  So what you want to do here is define an identity function as a helper to create type-safe documents.

I hoped to get better inference by using the type T to describe the whole `fieldsets` property instead of just the names.  But I am still having to use `as const` in order to get the literal string values from the object properties.

```
type FieldSet = {
    name: string;
    title: string;
}

type Field = {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    fieldset: string;
}

interface MyDocument<T extends ReadonlyArray<FieldSet>> {
    type: 'document';
    name: string;
    fieldsets: T;
    fields: Array<Field & {fieldset: T[number]['name']}>
}

const createDoc = <T extends ReadonlyArray<FieldSet>>(schema: MyDocument<T>): MyDocument<T> => schema;

const person = createDoc({
    type: 'document',
    name: 'person',
    fieldsets: [
        { name: 'personalDetails', title: 'Personal Details' }
    ] as const,
    fields: [
        { name: 'firstName', type: 'string', fieldset: 'personalDetails' },
        { name: 'surname', type: 'string', fieldset: 'otherSet' }, // error
    ],
});

// note: we need `as const` because the string is an object property

const identity = <T extends any>(value: T): T => value;

const a = identity('personalDetails'); // this infers a literal
const b = identity({ name: 'personalDetails', title: 'Personal Details' }); // this does not
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mMyxkm)